# What is the significance of a function without a 'self' argument insde a class?

Tags: python, class

```
class a:
    def b():
        ...
```

what is the Significance of b

thanks

---

```
class a:
    @staticmethod    
    def b():
        return 1
    def c(self):
        b()

print a.b()
print a().b()
print a().c()#error
```

and

```
class a:
    @staticmethod    
    def b():
        return 1
    def c(self):
        return self.b()

print a.b()
print a().b()
print a().c()
#1
#1
#1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you should use b() as staticmethod so that you can call it either from Class or Object of class e.g:

```
bash-3.2$ python
Python 2.6 (trunk:66714:66715M, Oct  1 2008, 18:36:04) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 5370)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class a:
...    @staticmethod
...    def b():
...       return 1
... 
>>> a_obj = a()
>>> print a.b()
1
>>> print a_obj.b()
1
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Syntax error. Try calling it.

```
>>> class a:
...     def b():
...             return 1
... 
>>> x=a()
>>> x.b()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: b() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

See also:

```
>>> class a:
...     def b():
...             return 1
...     def c(self):
...             return b()
... 
>>> a().c()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in c
NameError: global name 'b' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

in a class method `self` is the instance of the class the method is called on. beware that `self` is not a keyword in python just a conventional name given to the first argument of a method.

look at this example:

```
class A:

    def foo(self):
        print "I'm a.foo"

    @staticmethod
    def bar(s):
        print s

a = A()
a.foo()
A.foo(a)
```

here `a` is the instance of the class `A`. calling `a.foo()` you are invoking the method `foo` of the instance `a` while `A.foo(a)` invoke the method `foo` in the class `A` but passing the instance `a` as first argument and they are exactly the same thing (but never use the second form).

`staticmethod` is a decorator that let you define a class method as static. that function is no more a method and the first argument is not the instance of the class but is exactly the first argument you passed at that function:

```
a.bar("i'm a static method")
i'm a static method
A.bar("i'm a static method too")
i'm a static method too
```

PS. i don't want to bothering you but these are the very basis of python, [the python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html) is a nice start for the beginners.